# Is there a way to get data when processing on controller - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

I have a function on controller like crawl.

My Controller sometimes sleeping **10 seconds**, sometimes go away.

Like this:

```
 while ($someTrueFalse) {
        $data[]=$gettingdata;

        $wantToPassText="Received ".count($data)." - Sleeping 10 seconds";

        if($someControl){
            $someTrueFalse=false;
        }

        sleep(10);
    }

    return view('any_view');
```

How can I access the `$wantToPassText` variable from any views?

I tried,

```
setcookie('data',$wantToPassText,time()+60);
```

But i can't accessing while controller processing. I can access only when process finishes.

I tried, write database this `$wantToPassText`, but i can't access again while processing.

I mean,
i want write on page live process status. How is it possible?

Sorry my bad english...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your view won't be reached unless the loop finishes processing. your view can get the `$wantToPassText` if it's passed from the controller to the view.

Comment: I want to show to user the processing on waiting. I can use jquery ajax methods. Forexample, i want to show to user, “received 20 datas”. 3 seconds later show “received 40 datas” when while loop returning.   I tried set cookie each return of while loop, and try to read on another page with $_COOKIE but i didn’t success. Cookie setted only when controllers complete works.

Comment: put that in a job, implement socket

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: user uploads a file and you want to process it and show user some operational updates, innit?

Comment: No. User doesn’t upload anything. I will get thousands data from the other server using cUrl. So, i get some data, and sleep seconds. After get daha sleep seconds.

Comment: still the same type of problem. will write an answer based on your scenario.

Comment: Isn’t there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to store within `cache`.

You can store the value like so:

```
Cache::put(['text' => $wantToPassText], 1);
```

The second argument are the amount of **minutes** to cache (as of Laravel 5.8 this is now the amount of seconds).

Once you have completed the task, you can then clear the cache key/value:

```
Cache::forget('text');
```

Note: You should make sure to include the facade at the top of your controller:

```
use Cache
```